# Proving the number of non-fixed points in a self-inverse function is even

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I would like some guidance in how to solve this problem. I'm really trying to understand it, so hints and discussion would be preferred over a solution!

*Le problem:*

> A function $f:S \to S$ is called self-inverting if $f(f(x))=x$ for every $x \in S$. A point $x \in S$ is called a fixed point of $f$ if $f(x)=x$.
>   - Prove that, if $f:S \to S$ is a self-inverting function that has $k$ fixed points, then $|S|−k$ is even.

*My reasoning so far:*
When mapping $f:S \to S$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ the cardinality of $S$ is equal to $2n$, since every element in $S$ maps to a different element in $S$, except for the case of a fixed point, so that for every fixed point, the cardinality is $2n + k$? I am on the right track? If so, how should I approach proving this?

Comment: It may be easier if you partition $S$ into subsets of the form $\big\{x,f(x)\big\}$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool , what do you mean by partitioning? How do you partition a set into subsets?

Comment: A partition of a set $S$ is a collection $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_m\}$ of subsets of $S$ such that $A_1\cup A_2\cup\ldots \cup A_m=S$ and for $i\ne j$, $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$.  Basically, you split a set $S$ into smaller subsets.  For example, $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ can be partitioned into sets $\{1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\}$, or into $\{1,3,5\},\{2,4\}$.  In your case, you can use $f$ to partition $S$ into subsets that I mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is impossible because if S is infinite and k a natural number |S| - k is neither odd or even, concepts that apply only to intergers.

Answer (score -1):

checkout fixed points theorem.

|S| = |the number of fixed points| + |the number of non-fixed points|

what is |the number of fixed points|?

f(x) = x -> k=1 this means in your set S you have the 1 number that maps to itself. |k| where k=1 is 1.

What is |the number of non-fixed points|?

f'(f(x)) = x .
1 non-fixed point map to 1 'other' point in S.  If there was a number n that described the number of points for x.  Then we would have n non-fixed points mapping to n 'other' points.  To count this number of points I would describe this as 2n points.

This holds true for k=2 (and beyond). You have two numbers that map to themselves and the rest map to another number and back again.(2n)

The cardinality of your set has to be the 2n + k.  If you |S|= 2n + k and you subtract k, then you simply have 2n points.

Comment: I can kind of follow, but I'm wondering why you were downvoted!

Comment: I looked up the [Fixed Points Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPointTheorem.html), but now I'm wondering if this implies that there exists only a single fixed point! Is that so?

Comment: I wish it was explained in a comment too. maybe I should not have given the answer, but given hints to it... can't say I'm an expert but was trying to reason it.

Comment: Fixed point theorem doesn't say there is one point, only that there is one point that maps to itself.